# Выходит непонятная ошибка, после парсинга курса валют на Python

Tags: python, парсер

Делаю парсинг курса доллара. Уже доделал, но тут выходит вот такая ошибка

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Поискал в паутине, не нашел. Прошу вашей помощи!

Вот сам код, заранее спасибо!)

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time 
import smtplib 

class Currency:
    # Ссылки
    DOLLAR_RUB = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0&rlz=1C1DVJR_ruRU878RU879&oq=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.4895j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
    headers = {'User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}

    current_converted_price = 0
    difference = 3 

    def __init__(self):
        # Установка курса валюты при создании объекта
        self.current_converted_price = float(self.get_currency_price().replace(",", "."))

    # Метод для получения курса валюты
    def get_currency_price(self):
        # Парсим всю страницу
        full_page = requests.get(self.DOLLAR_RUB, headers=self.headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')

        convert = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "DFlfde", "class": "SwHCTb", "data-precision": 2})
        return convert[0].text

    # Проверка изменения валюты
    def check_currency(self):
        currency = float(self.get_currency_price().replace(",", "."))
        if currency >= self.current_converted_price + self.difference:
            print("Курс сильно вырос, может пора что-то делать?")
            self.send_mail()
        elif currency <= self.current_converted_price - self.difference:
            print("Курс сильно упал, может пора что-то делать?")
            self.send_mail()

        print("Сейчас курс: 1 доллар = " + str(currency))
        time.sleep(3) 
        self.check_currency()

    # Отправка почты через SMTP
    def send_mail(self):
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()

        server.login('dyrtage@gmail.com', 'yffuxdgmgainuhsn')

        subject = 'Курс валют'
        body = 'Курс доллара изменился' 
        message = f'Subject: {subject}\n{body}'

        server.sendmail(
            'dyrt2006@gmail.com',
            'dyrtage@gmail.com',
            message
        )
        server.quit()

currency = Currency()
currency.check_currency()
```

Comment: У вас в словаре `headers`  ключ `User-Agent` в разных кавычках. В настоящем коде так же? А вообще ошибка очень понятная - где-то у множества вызывается `items`  как у словаря. А у множества нет такого атрибута. В ошибке также должно быть написано в каком модуле и на какой строчке это происходит.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не заметил кавычки, все проблемы были из-за них